# R: calculate number of distinct categories in the specified time frame

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, distinct-values

here's some dummy data:

```
  user_id       date category
       27 2016-01-01    apple
       27 2016-01-03    apple
       27 2016-01-05     pear
       27 2016-01-07     plum
       27 2016-01-10    apple
       27 2016-01-14     pear
       27 2016-01-16     plum
       11 2016-01-01    apple
       11 2016-01-03     pear
       11 2016-01-05     pear
       11 2016-01-07     pear
       11 2016-01-10    apple
       11 2016-01-14    apple
       11 2016-01-16    apple
```

I'd like to calculate **for each `user_id` the number of distinct `categories` in the specified time period (e.g. in the past 7, 14 days), including the current order**

The solution would look like this:

```
 user_id       date category distinct_7 distinct_14
      27 2016-01-01    apple          1           1
      27 2016-01-03    apple          1           1
      27 2016-01-05     pear          2           2
      27 2016-01-07     plum          3           3
      27 2016-01-10    apple          3           3
      27 2016-01-14     pear          3           3
      27 2016-01-16     plum          3           3
      11 2016-01-01    apple          1           1
      11 2016-01-03     pear          2           2
      11 2016-01-05     pear          2           2
      11 2016-01-07     pear          2           2
      11 2016-01-10    apple          2           2
      11 2016-01-14    apple          2           2
      11 2016-01-16    apple          1           2
```

I posted similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615967/r-calculate-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-specific-event-in-the-past-and-futur) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020670/r-calculate-cumulative-sums-and-counts-since-the-last-occurrence-of-a-value), however none of it referred to counting cumulative unique values for the specified time period. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why does it start with `0`?

Comment: that was my typo, now corrected, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the values in `distinct_7` are correct?  If I look at 2016-01-10, should it start as a new group.  Also, if you look at the value of `distinct_7`  for `user_id` 11, it starts at 0.

Comment: in `distinct_7`, between `2016-01-10` and `2016-01-03` there were in total 3 categories for `user 27` and 2 for `user 11`. Does it make sense now?

Comment: You can iterate over `date`, i.e. `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(user_id) %>% mutate(distinct_7 = map_int(date, ~n_distinct(category[date >= .x - 7 & date <= .x])), distinct_14 = map_int(date, ~n_distinct(category[date >= .x - 14 & date <= .x])))`, though I think there's probably a more elegant way to do this with `zoo::rollapply` or the like.

Comment: should `11 2016-01-01 ` not be `1` for both output cases?

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593453/r-calculate-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-specific-event-in-a-specified-time-f/41594675#41594675)

Comment: @alistaire: this works very well for me, although it takes time to process. Still, if you write an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: @Aramis7d: thanks for spotting this, it's now corrected

Comment: @alistaire: I just tried to use your solution to calculate cumulative sums of numerical values, e.g.: `order_value_minus7 = map_int(order_date, ~cumsum(order_value[order_date >= .x - 7 & order_date <= .x]))`, but it returns  `Error: object 'order_value' not found`. Why can't the same approach work universally, or can it? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Fwiw, the data.table analogue of `n_distinct` (in alistaire's comment-answer) is `uniqueN`.

Comment: You don't have a variable called `order_value` in what you show above. I'm not posting an answer because the data doesn't match your desired result, I believe because the desired result is miscalculated, if I understand what you want. Also, I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it, anyway.

Comment: @alistaire: sure, that's absolutely understandable. I asked about `order_value` because your solution looked pretty universal and I thought it would require only a small tweak to use it for numerical variable. Anyway, why do you think that the desired solution is miscalculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tidyverse, you can use `map_int` to iterate over a set of values and simplify to an integer à la `sapply` or `vapply`. Count distinct occurrences with `n_distinct` (like `length(unique(...))`) of an object subset by comparisons or the helper `between`, with a minimum set by the appropriate amount subtracted from that day, and you're set.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(user_id) %>% 
    mutate(distinct_7  = map_int(date, ~n_distinct(category[between(date, .x - 7, .x)])), 
           distinct_14 = map_int(date, ~n_distinct(category[between(date, .x - 14, .x)])))

## Source: local data frame [14 x 5]
## Groups: user_id [2]
## 
##    user_id       date category distinct_7 distinct_14
##      <int>     <date>   <fctr>      <int>       <int>
## 1       27 2016-01-01    apple          1           1
## 2       27 2016-01-03    apple          1           1
## 3       27 2016-01-05     pear          2           2
## 4       27 2016-01-07     plum          3           3
## 5       27 2016-01-10    apple          3           3
## 6       27 2016-01-14     pear          3           3
## 7       27 2016-01-16     plum          3           3
## 8       11 2016-01-01    apple          1           1
## 9       11 2016-01-03     pear          2           2
## 10      11 2016-01-05     pear          2           2
## 11      11 2016-01-07     pear          2           2
## 12      11 2016-01-10    apple          2           2
## 13      11 2016-01-14    apple          2           2
## 14      11 2016-01-16    apple          1           2
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using [runner](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runner/index.html) package. You can use any R function on running windows with `runner` function. Code below obtains desided output, which is past 7-days + current and past 14-days + current (current 8 and 15 days):

```
df <- read.table(
  text = "  user_id       date category
       27 2016-01-01    apple
  27 2016-01-03    apple
  27 2016-01-05     pear
  27 2016-01-07     plum
  27 2016-01-10    apple
  27 2016-01-14     pear
  27 2016-01-16     plum
  11 2016-01-01    apple
  11 2016-01-03     pear
  11 2016-01-05     pear
  11 2016-01-07     pear
  11 2016-01-10    apple
  11 2016-01-14    apple
  11 2016-01-16    apple", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("integer", "Date", "character"))



library(dplyr)
library(runner)
df %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(distinct_7  = runner(category, k = 7 + 1, idx = date, 
                              f = function(x) length(unique(x))),
         distinct_14 = runner(category, k = 14 + 1, idx = date, 
                              f = function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

More informations in [package](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/) and [function](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/reference/runner.html) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two `data.table` solutions, one with two nested `lapply`and the other using *non-equi joins*.

The first one is a rather clumsy `data.table` solution but it reproduces the expected answer. And it would work for an arbitrary number of time frames. (Although @alistaire's concise `tidyverse` solution he had suggested in his comment could be modified as well).

It uses two nested `lapply`. The first one loops over the time frames, the second one over the dates. The tempory result is joined with the original data and then reshaped from long to wide format so that we will end with a separate column for each of the time frames.

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- rbindlist(
  lapply(c(7L, 14L), 
         function(ldays) rbindlist(
           lapply(unique(dt$date), 
                  function(ldate) {
                    dt[between(date, ldate - ldays, ldate), 
                       .(distinct = sprintf("distinct_%02i", ldays), 
                         date = ldate, 
                         N = uniqueN(category)), 
                       by = .(user_id)]
                  })
         )
  )
)
dcast(tmp[dt, on=c("user_id", "date")], 
      ... ~ distinct, value.var = "N")[order(-user_id, date, category)] 
#          date user_id category distinct_07 distinct_14
# 1: 2016-01-01      27    apple           1           1
# 2: 2016-01-03      27    apple           1           1
# 3: 2016-01-05      27     pear           2           2
# 4: 2016-01-07      27     plum           3           3
# 5: 2016-01-10      27    apple           3           3
# 6: 2016-01-14      27     pear           3           3
# 7: 2016-01-16      27     plum           3           3
# 8: 2016-01-01      11    apple           1           1
# 9: 2016-01-03      11     pear           2           2
#10: 2016-01-05      11     pear           2           2
#11: 2016-01-07      11     pear           2           2
#12: 2016-01-10      11    apple           2           2
#13: 2016-01-14      11    apple           2           2
#14: 2016-01-16      11    apple           1           2
```

Here is a variant [following a suggestion by @Frank](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35172493#35172493) which uses `data.table`'s *non-equi joins*  instead of the second `lapply`:

```
tmp <- rbindlist(
  lapply(c(7L, 14L), 
         function(ldays) {
           dt[.(user_id = user_id, dago = date - ldays, d = date), 
              on=.(user_id, date >= dago, date <= d), 
              .(distinct = sprintf("distinct_%02i", ldays),
                N = uniqueN(category)), 
              by = .EACHI]
         }
  )
)[, date := NULL]
# 
dcast(tmp[dt, on=c("user_id", "date")], 
      ... ~ distinct, value.var = "N")[order(-user_id, date, category)]
```

Data:

```
dt <- fread("user_id       date category
       27 2016-01-01    apple
       27 2016-01-03    apple
       27 2016-01-05     pear
       27 2016-01-07     plum
       27 2016-01-10    apple
       27 2016-01-14     pear
       27 2016-01-16     plum
       11 2016-01-01    apple
       11 2016-01-03     pear
       11 2016-01-05     pear
       11 2016-01-07     pear
       11 2016-01-10    apple
       11 2016-01-14    apple
       11 2016-01-16    apple")
dt[, date := as.IDate(date)]
```

BTW: The wording *in the past 7, 14 days* is somewhat misleading as the time periods actually consist of 8 and 15 days, resp.